# Select elements from drop down in a loop selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I am getting all options from drop down, but I cannot select them, maybe somebody can help me, how to select each value from drop down in a loop:

```
<select id="1234" class="dropdown">
    <option value="3">HelloWorld</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">GoodBye</option>
    <option value="2">Name</option>
    <option value="5">Surname</option>
</select>
```

My code:

```
var elements = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("1234")).FindElements(By.TagName("option"));
for (var i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++){
    elements[i].Click();
}
```

No errors appear, just not select the value from dropdown

Comment: Do you have to click on dropdown list first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, can you please make sure there is no any other
   element(s) with an id of "1234"? Selenium FindElement By.Id will
   always find the first element that matches your criteria.
2. Second of all, Can you please try introducing a bit waiting between
   selecting the dropdown menu and selecting its items, you may need to
   break your

   var elements = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("1234")).FindElements(By.TagName("option"));

   into two steps and put a waiting inbetween. Sometimes, your clicking command is too fast for a dropdown menu to display its dropdown menu.
3. For diagnostic purpose, you can use element.getAttribute('one element') to find out an attribute value for your dropdown menu options, just to make sure you have truly found them.
4. Does this dropdown list belong to an iframe? But you have said there was no error so it might not belong to an iframe.

Comment: Thank you adding wait time helps me

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper way to do this

```
SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("1234")));
foreach (IWebElement option in dropdown.Options)
{
    // you may need a slight delay here to give the page a chance to respond and make the change
    option.Click();
}
```